# Listen for "mongojs" connection errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

Mongojs is thin wrapper for mongodb-native library, but the only problem is that I am unable to listen for errors ?

The main errors which needs to be handled are connection erros, could not or lost connection.
Here is the example, that I have tried so far.

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');

var db = mongojs.connect('reallyRandomStringShouldGiveError', ['sessions', 'unknown']);

// This does not work
db.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('Catch ', err);
});

db.sessions.insert({ a: 1 });

db.unkknown.find({ a: 1}, function (err, result) {
        console.log(err, result);
});
```

And the code from "mongojs" library which should emit the errors again [mongojs source](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs/blob/master/index.js)

```
var connect = function(config, collections) {
    var connectionString = parseConfig(config);

    var ondb = thunky(function(callback) {
        mongodb.Db.connect(connectionString, function(err, db) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            that.client = db;
            db.on('error', function(err) {
                process.nextTick(function() {
                                    // Errors seems to be emitted again
                    that.emit('error', err);
                });
            });
            callback(null, db);
        });
    });
    var that = new Database(ondb);

    .....

    return that;
};
```

Adding the process listener is not the best option.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this that wasn't working for you then:

```
db.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Catch ', err);
});
```

because it was an issue posted on Github that finally got solved, have a look [here](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs/issues/149)... so you can now catch it with any problems (I am using it that way inside some of my coding and it is working!).

You can go further, and pass an `err` parameter inside your callbacks, for example like this:

```
db.collection.insert( { foo: "foo_value" }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(" Woops! The error took place here... ");
    } else {
        console.log(" Everything went neat! ");
    }
});
```

...to know where that error took place. This is working really nice for me.